# Android Studio 0.8.1 gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I had a working project while using 0.6.1 and after I updated to 0.8.1 I got this error

> Error: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Starting new projects also gives the same error as soon as gradle starts to sync.

IDE Fatal Errors Console:

```
Error on line 8: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".: Error on line 8: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 8: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:364)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.readSettings(SettingsConnectionService.java:72)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getSettingValue(SettingsConnectionService.java:112)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getServiceUrl(SettingsConnectionService.java:104)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStatisticsService.areStatisticsAuthorized(AndroidStatisticsService.java:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.addBuildRecordImmediately(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent$1.run(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:364)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.readSettings(SettingsConnectionService.java:72)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getSettingValue(SettingsConnectionService.java:112)
at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getServiceUrl(SettingsConnectionService.java:104)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStatisticsService.areStatisticsAuthorized(AndroidStatisticsService.java:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.addBuildRecordImmediately(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent$1.run(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I used to encounter Gradle Sync Failed too, so I downloaded it manually.

For latest version of Gradle (currently 2.0) you can download it from [here](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip).

Then extract the zip file to any location and then on your Android Studio, go to File>Settings>Gradle and select Local Distribution and select your Gradle folder address.

This worked for me so I'm suggesting it to you. Cheers.

Comment: I realised that the proxy server at my university did not allow certain dependencies to be downloaded so I used my own Internet connection and it got resolved. Thanks anyway